# Displaying what categories a product belongs to on a single-entry page

Tags: categories

I have 3 category parents with several children in each.

For a single entry product page, I would like to list which categories the product belongs to (children only), with a single header for each category parent:

Publisher: (parent id 22) 
Designer: (parent id 45)
Genre: (parent id 8)

There could be multiple children categories for Designer and Genre.

Ideally I would like to use conditional statements that spit out:

```
if publisher is checked then <p>Publisher: <a href="#">publishercategoryname</a> </p>

if designer is checked then <p>Publisher: <a href="#">designercategoryname1</a>, <a href="#">designercategoryname2</a>, <a href="#">designercategoryname3</a> </p>

if genre is checked then <p>Genre(s): <a href="#">genrecategoryname1</a>, <a href="#">genrecategoryname2</a>, <a href="#">genrecategoryname3</a> </p>
```

I would like the parent to show up just once, with the children category names nested.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you can do some complicated stuff with GW Categories, I would probably first use separate category groups for these three things instead of nesting parent-child categories. It would simplify things greatly and create better separation of concerns, since your top-level categories are not semantically related to each other - you're basically just faking headings which would be better suited as individual category groups.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="example" disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" style="linear"}
       {if group_start}<p>{cat_group_name}: {/if}
       <a href="{path=category/{cat_url_title}}">{cat_name}</a>
       {if group_end}</p>{if:else} ,{/if}
     {/exp:gwcode_categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I agree with you. I just created new category groups for each, instead of using parents. Still not sure how to code it so that I can get the categories for each group id listed though. They may not always be populated, so needs a conditional, and I want them listed with the group id name only once. Any thoughts?

Comment: edited answer to add an example - as with most things to do with EE categories, using the GW plugin will make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

This excellent add-on http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories will do exactly what you need. Check it out!